# Is there a way to transmit live voice through radio without a soundcard on raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, radio, pifm

Is it possible to transmit live voice through raspberry pi 3 without a usb soundcard
I only have a hradset with a mic
And I am a beginner
If possible let me know the answer in a simple way
Thank you

Comment: They make USB microphones that may work. They also make microphone to USB adapters. But most important microphone headset to USB. Hopefully that would work, I never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to transmit live voice through raspberry pi 3 without a usb soundcard

Whatever means must logically involve additional hardware, and a USB soundcard is almost certainly the cheapest and easiest option.

I say "logically involve additional hardware" because in order to use the mic, you must plug it into something attached to the pi, since there is no built in microphone jack.

Comment: Can I do it with a 3.5mm mic?

Comment: If you mean, a USB sound card/dongle with a 3.5mm jack, then yes.

Comment: https://5.imimg.com/data5/FC/NC/MY-10981130/collar-mic-283-5mm-microphone-29-500x500.jpg
This is what I have.
Can I plug it into the raspberry and do the trick?

Comment: There is a jack on the pi that sort of fits that device, but it is an _output_ jack, and I think it has video on it, not audio.  If you want to plug a microphone in, you need a sound card with a microphone jack.

Answer (score 0):

The Pi 3 (and Pi 4) do not have microphone hardware.

https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=187955

You could use a bluetooth headset instead. Of course, this is a pain because of the need to keep an extra battery charged.

Comment: The OP states that he already has a headset.

Comment: Yes, but he does not say whether it is a 3.5 mm wired headset or a bluetooth headset.